# Use a switch statement to create file directories?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io, switch-statement

I'm creating an app that's going to be installed on a number of devices and I'd like to automate the setup of the file system on each device's local disk as much as possible. Rather than use dozens of if statements is there a more streamlined way to do this using a switch statement?

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(arctopithecusGalleryPath) == false)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(arctopithecusGalleryPath);              
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a method for that:

```
public void CreateIfNotExists(string path)
{
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) == false)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);              
    }
}
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
CreateIfNotExists(arctopithecusGalleryPath);
```

Or if you have multiple directories you can add them to list and call this method inside foreach statement:

```
List<string> folders = new List<string>();
folders.Add("a folder to create");
// add more folders
foreach(var folder in folders)
{
    CreateIfNotExists(folder);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store variables in array & loop them to avoid multiple IFs.

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { arctopithecusGalleryPath, arctopithecusGalleryPath1, arctopithecusGalleryPath3 };

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
       if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(array[i]) == false){
       System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(array[i]);              
}
```